# Can a web page access data being sent to a computer via USB

Tags: java, flash, usb

What are the options (or is it possible at all) for a web page (running on a remote server, not localhost) to access a data stream (not video) coming in via the USB port of the local computer?

Ideally this would work cross-platform (Windows, Unix, Mac anyway) and the local computer would not have to download/install anything to make it work (beyond what you can reasonably expect a computer to have)

An embedded Java applet seems the only way, but I'm wondering if there's any other technologies that could do it.

If the restriction is lifted so that the user can install something (basic for non-techies, not setting up a local server running node.js for example) does that make more things possible (Flash?)

Comment: There are some security concerns in your requirements...

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create an ActiveX component to do this. I am not sure if it can be portable on different OS.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one way that you can interact with the usb port: You would have to set up a socket server on the remote host which would redirect your network traffic to the serial / usb port and vice versa.

This doesn't completely fulfil the requirement, but I think it's the only way to do it in Actionscript